# Animación automática en slider sin usar la propiedad autoplay

Tags: javascript, css, django, slider

tengo un slider que funciona a través de controles, pero necesito que sea automático a la vez, no puedo usar la función autoPlay porque ya tengo un slider que la está usando; podrían decirme de qué otra manera lo puedo hacer funcionar? Gracias de antemano.
Este es el código html:

```
<div class="cliente">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <i id="left"><</i>
    <ul class="carousel">
      {% for cliente in cliente %}
      <li class="card">
         <div class="foto"><img src="{{ cliente.logo.url }}" alt="" draggable="false"></div>
      </li> 
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <i id="right">></i>
  </div>
  </div>
```

El código en javascript, hasta ahí todo bien, pero no sé como hacerlo automático sin hacer uso de la función autoplay

```
const carousel = document.querySelector(".wrapper ul");
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const arrowBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper i");
const firstCardWidth = carousel.querySelector(".card").offsetWidth;
const carouselChildrens = [...carousel.children];

let cardPerView = Math.round(carousel.offsetWidth / firstCardWidth);

carouselChildrens.slice(-cardPerView).reverse().forEach(card => {
    carousel.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",card.outerHTML);
});
carouselChildrens.slice(0, cardPerView).forEach(card => {
    carousel.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",card.outerHTML);
});

arrowBtns.forEach( btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    carousel.scrollLeft += btn.id === "left" ? -firstCardWidth : firstCardWidth;
  });
});

const infiniteScroll = () => {
    if(carousel.scrollLeft === 0){
        carousel.classList.add("no-transition")
        carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.scrollWidth - (2 * carousel.offsetWidth);
        carousel.classList.remove("no-transition")
    }
    else if(Math.ceil(carousel.scrollLeft) === carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.offsetWidth){
        carousel.classList.add("no-transition")
        carousel.scrollLeft = carousel.offsetWidth;
        carousel.classList.remove("no-transition")
    }
    
}
```